# Como llenar una tabla HTML con varias consultas

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla que muestra los inventarios de cada producto, los campos son los siguientes: Producto, Inventario Inicial, Inventario Actual, Producción e Inventario nuevo, que es la suma de Inventario Actual y Producción, la cuestión es que Producto viene de otra tabla llamada Productos y Los demás campos vienen de la tabla Inventario, la única relación entre estas dos es el ID del producto, que es con lo que se sabe cual inventario se va a editar, las he intentado llamar a las dos para mostrar todos los registros en una sola tabla pero sucede esto

[image: Los datos se muestran desalineados]
Mi codigo es el siguiente

```
<?php
    
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT Inventario_Inicial, Inventario_Actual, Produccion, Inventario_Actual+Produccion FROM Inventario');
    
$statement->execute();
    
while($datos_inventario = $statement->fetch() ) { ?>                        
    
<tr>
<td><?php echo $datos_inventario["Inventario_Inicial"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $datos_inventario["Inventario_Actual"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $datos_inventario["Produccion"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $datos_inventario["Inventario_Actual+Produccion"]; ?></td>
                              
<?php  } ?>
    
<?php
    
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT ID, Nombre_Producto FROM Productos');
    
$statement->execute();
    
while($datos_producto = $statement->fetch() ) { ?>

<td><?php echo $datos_producto["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></td>
<td><a href="funcion_modificar_inventarios.php?ID=<?php echo $datos_producto["ID"]; ?>" class="btn bg-orange margin"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                              </tr>
<?php  } ?> 

</tbody>
<tfoot>
 <tr>
<th>Producto</th>
<th>Inventario Inicial</th>
<th>Inventario Actual</th>
<th>Inventario Produccion</th>
<th>Inventario Nuevo</th>
<th>Editar</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Las tablas son las siguientes

```
Productos:
Id INT AI
Nombre_Producto VARCHAR 11
Tipo_Producto ENUM

Inventario:
Id
ProductoID (Relacionada con el id del producto)
Inventario_Inicial INT
Inventario_Actual INT
Produccion INT
Inventario_Actual + Produccion (Esta no es una columna)
```

Comment: Deberias agregar la estructura de las tablas

Comment: ya mismo lo hago

Comment: Debes hacer un join de tus tablas, revisa si te sirve esto: `select p.Nombre_Producto, `i.Inventario Inicial`, `i.Inventario Actual`, i.produccion, (`i.Inventario Inicial`+produccion) as total from producto p inner join inventario ion p.id=i.ProductoID `

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras me podrias explicar que es ese AS Total

Comment: Diablos! Veo que inventario inicial e inventario actual tienen espacio, para poder usarlos en una consulta debes ponerlos entre el acento invertido. Sí lo puse en la consulta, pero siendo caracter reservado los usó para otra cosa. A ver si así sí salen: `select p.Nombre_Producto, ``i.Inventario Inicial``, ``i.Inventario Actual``, i.produccion, (``i.Inventario Inicial``+produccion) as total from producto p inner join inventario on p.id=i.ProductoID `

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras No llevan espacio es barra baja

Comment: Ok, solo cambia los nombres y debería funcionar

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras lo intente y ya no muestra nada te adjunto la consulta  ```SELECT p.Nombre_Producto, i.Inventario_Inicial, i.Inventario_Actual, i.Produccion, i.Inventario_Actual+i.Produccion FROM Producto p INNER JOIN Inventario i ON p.ID=i.ProductoID```

Comment: pruébalo directamente en mysql, debería funcionar

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Ok dame un minuto

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Funciona en SQL pero en PHP no

Comment: Bruno, tendrás que modificar la estructura de tu página. Con el producto en la misma consulta ya no te hace falta la segunda llamada a sql (donde pides el nombre del producto). No estoy seguro por qué no se muestra en PHP, podrías intentar modificando `$datos_inventario["Inventario_Inicial"];` por algo como `$datos_inventario["i.Inventario_Inicial"];`

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Podrias publicar tu comentario como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer paso sería modificar tu consulta a algo como esto:

`SELECT p.Nombre_Producto, i.Inventario_Inicial, i.Inventario_Actual, i.Produccion, i.Inventario_Actual+i.Produccion FROM Producto p INNER JOIN Inventario i ON p.ID=i.ProductoID`

Con eso nos podemos deshacer de todo este código (hay que borrarlo):

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT ID, Nombre_Producto FROM Productos');
    
$statement->execute();
    
while($datos_producto = $statement->fetch() ) { ?>

<td><?php echo $datos_producto["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></td>
```

Y para finalizar tendrías que modificar `$datos_inventario["Inventario_Inicial"];` por algo así: `$datos_inventario["i.Inventario_Inicial"];`: se le antepone  la tabla de donde estamos pidiendo los datos.

Saludos!

Comment: No se muestran los registros, aparece la tabla en blanco, que crees que sea

Comment: Lo siento... he buscado cuál podría ser el problema pero noencuentro nada...

Comment: Gracias de cualquier forma :)